Why is aws-serverless-express routing my incoming request to the GET / path instead of my POST /retrieveInfo path?
Here is my index.mjs file
/* global fetch */
import express from 'express';
import serverless from 'aws-serverless-express';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({'pizza': 'potato'});
})

app.post('/retrieveInfo', (request, response) => {
  response.json({'pizza': 'pop'});
});

const server = serverless.createServer(app);

export const handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log("Event: ", event);
  console.log("Context: ", context);
  serverless.proxy(server, event, context);
};

The event JSON object that gets passed in when I make a POST request to the /retrieveInfo path is this. I've somewhat censored it, though I don't expect that to affect the routing.
{
  version: '2.0',
  routeKey: 'POST /retrieveInfo',
  rawPath: '/retrieveInfo',
  rawQueryString: '',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br',
    'content-length': '23',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    host: '-----',
    'request-start-time': '1713067589102',
    'user-agent': '-----',
    'x-amzn-trace-id': '-----',
    'x-forwarded-for': '-----',
    'x-forwarded-port': '443',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'
  },
  requestContext: {
    accountId: '------',
    apiId: '-----',
    domainName: '------',
    domainPrefix: '-----',
    http: {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/retrieveInfo',
      protocol: 'HTTP/1.1',
      sourceIp: '-----',
      userAgent: '-----'
    },
    requestId: '-----',
    routeKey: 'POST /retrieveInfo',
    stage: '$default',
    time: '14/Apr/2024:04:06:29 +0000',
    timeEpoch: 1713067589287
  },
  body: '{"domain":"reddit.com"}',
  isBase64Encoded: false
}

The only integration currently attached to the API Gateway is a POST /retrieveInfo and if I add some logging to the GET / handler, I see this route: route: Route { path: '/', stack: [ [Layer] ], methods: { get: true } },. Is there something wrong with the way I'm using this package?
